# Passing chords to and returning music with Lilypond music substitution functions

Tags: scheme, guile, lilypond, music-notation

I am trying to write functions in Lilypond which take a chord (or list of pitches) as an argument and return music with said chord inserted into a rhythm. More specifically, I would like the function to be invoked in some way like this:

```
\chordFunction <c ef f af>
% or
\chordFunction #'(c ef f af)
```

and to return Lilypond code like so:

```
\tuplet 3/2 {<c ef f af>4 <c ef f af>8~} <c ef f af>2
```

[image: pretty picture of desired output once engraved]
I have tried

```
jazzsyncoA = 
#(define-music-function
  (parser location chord)
  (symbol-list-or-music?)
  #{
    \tuplet 3/2 {$<chord>4 $<chord>8~} $<chord>2
  #}
)
```

but that throws

```
error: GUILE signaled an error for the expression beginning here
    \tuplet 3/2 {$
                  <chord>4 $<chord>8~} $<chord>2
```

along with other errors when I attempt invocation. How should I write functions to accomplish this? Am I approaching the problem improperly?

---

I've looked in the [Lilypond docs on predefined type predicates](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/predefined-type-predicates), but I can't recognize any of potential use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're more or less in the right direction. You could look at [this LilyPond doc page](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/extending/adding-articulation-to-notes-_0028example_0029) to see how you might get started writing a pure Scheme function to solve this and other problems.

As for your function, if you want to use your function like `\chordFunction <c ef f af>`, then you could `ly:music?` as the predicate:

```
\version "2.18.0"
\language "english"

jazzsyncoA = #(define-music-function (parser location my-notes) (ly:music?)
    #{
        \tuplet 3/2 {  #my-notes q8~ } q2
    #}
)

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \clef "bass"
        \key c \minor
        \new Voice = "one" {
            \jazzsyncoA <c ef f af>4
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the the same result as what's in your picture. I tested this on version 2.19.82, but I'm guessing that it will work on 2.18.0 as well. Hope that it helps!